# How to connect and query through ODBC connection a Sage 200 database?

Tags: c#, odbc, sage-erp

How can I connect and fetch data from a Sage 200 database through a ODBC connection using C#?

I have no code to show because I'm stuck even with the connection string part...
I found tutorial or article only about MySQL, Microsoft Server, and etc..

**[EDIT]**

I have solved, the problem was that I was using `SqlConnection` instead of the `OdbcConnection` class.

Comment: Do any of these links help? http://help.sagecrm.com/on_premise/en/2018R1/dev/Content/Developer/WS_EgIntroToWebServices.htm https://simonsage200.wordpress.com/reports-reports-reports/pulling-information-from-sage-200-into-excel-using-odbc/

Comment: @mjwills Thank you, but I can't find anything useful to can understand how to make the connection and after that to fetch data from the DB.